# If permissions[read/write] to a DB table[oracle] are modified, is a server restart required?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, websphere

I am facing an issue where during the load of a new table the permission were not provided. When the server started up and hibernate performed an initialization no errors were reported.

When we ran our test in the application, we noticed the following issue:

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.**

So the DBA provided the appropriate permissions.

Once we re-ran the test, we see the same issue posted.

My question is that is a server restart required to fix this issue? And why is it needed if there was no update to the database structure itself? Is this the way that hibernate works?

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: what kind of data do you are managing in that table? Could show us the table schema and the hibernate config related?

Comment: How did you get that table (name)? There is an unfortunate difference of scanning all tables (names), when using the connection's DatabaseMetaData or the Oracle specific system table. But I take it, that you are having some specific tests.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to restart the server. That error can also mean that you are attempting to access a table in a different schema than the one you are connected to and are not supplying the owning schema as a prefix nor using a synonym to access the table.

So, for instance, you could try:

```
<owning schema>.table_name
```

instead of simply:

```
table_name
```

Another possibility is that the database role you are using to access the table is a non-default role, meaning you would need to issue a `set role` command to enable it.

Comment: That was the first thought as well. But all the other tables are being loaded properly and it is only when there is a call to this table that  the issue is seen.